How to observe app settings change in the app?
Is there any way to observe settings change for my app? I mean the settings that user can change in the "Settings", particular for my app, like battery optimizations, background restrictions etc. Here is what settings I mean in example of Gmail app:

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Changing anything in this screen is supposed to close the app and have a fresh start of it, even if it was in the background
when you change anything in this settings screen, does your app remain in the state you left off?

@AbdallahA.Odeh it's not true that the app should have "fresh" start after change settings. App can start from onResume after changes of settings. My app remain in the state I left off.

I found only one method, that indicate background restrictions:
isBackgroundRestricted() for SDK > 28
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager#isBackgroundRestricted().
Example of usage:
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.P) {
        val activityManager: ActivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
        Timber.w("Is app background restricted: ${activityManager.isBackgroundRestricted}")
    }

Please leave a comment if you found more methods like this.
